# Should I run as a docker user, and keep sshd running all the time, or as root but start/stop sshd on demand

Tags: ssh, docker

I'm creating a docker container that will be used as a reverse tunnel. I'm now looking to harden the solution but I've an interesting dilemma and I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Current the container hosts a simple web app that when it's given a POST to an endpoint will start sshd, and use autossh to create a reverse tunnel to a jump box. When it's given the correct POST to close the endpoint it stops sshd and autossh.

This works great.

The issue is I now would like to stop the container running everything as root, but running as any other user doesn't have the correct permission to start or stop the ssh server and I get this error:

```
service ssh start
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/sshd': Permission denied
```

In searching, it looks like I just can't start/stop sshd without elevated permissions. I could start sshd before changing the user in the docker build file.

Which compromise is the best? Run as a low privilege user, but have sshd running all the time (but not really connectable), or run as root and start/stop sshd as and when it's needed?

Comment: you could use sudo and limit it to one command, but I don't see here any business relationship